# Why does type L not have any type parameters even though it extends ArrayList?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

This is my code:

```
private <T,L extends ArrayList<? extends T>> L Foo(L<T> list1) {
    L list2 = new ArrayList<T>();

    //more code

}
```

I'm using IDEA and get the following error message for the method parameter:

`Type 'L' does not have type parameters`

and the following error message for creating the ArrayList:

```
Incompatible types. <br>Required: L <br> Found: java.utils.ArrayList<T>;
```

Why does this happen? `L` extends ArrayList so it should have the same type parameters right?

Comment: What is the purpose of `Foo`?  Because `L` is defined to extend `ArrayList<? extends T>`, you can't assign any `ArrayList` to `L`.

Comment: @rgettman This is part of a couple methods I am using to find unique objects in an input list of an arbitrary dimension.

Comment: you are trying to create `L`, which expects a class that extends an ArrayList, but youre trying to create `ArrayList`.

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. It'll help if you explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: `L` is a type variable. Type variables can't have type parameters of their own. (At least, not in Java.) If you want `L` to be a subtype of a parameterized type, you need to do that where you define `L` (e.g. `L extends List<? extends T>`). But you can't redefine the parameters of `L` elsewhere, and you can't require that `L` actually be a generic type -- it could be a concrete subclass of a generic class, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not known if `ArrayList<T>` is an `L`. For example, `L` could be a `MyArrayListImpl<T>`.

I think this is what you want:

```
private <T> List<T> Foo(List<T> list1) {
    List<T> list2 = new ArrayList<T>();

    //more code

}
```

Comment: Not a `LinkedList`, perhaps, but a `MySpecialExtendedArrayList`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't know what I was thinking. I fixed the answer. Thx.